# Where should I find data source bind with deployed war in websphere

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal

Where should I find data source bind with deployed war in websphere

I tried searching data source under 'All Applications' where I have deployed the .war

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try navigating to below path:
Enterprise Applications > PULSESIT_SURCHARGE_SIT_war > Resource references

Answer (score 1):

Datasources are found in the WebSphere Application Server Admin Console by going to Resources -> JDBC -> Datasources.

Comment: Thnx #Carlos from  JDBC -> Datasource we can get information of all the Datasource, where as i was looking for specific datasource bind to deployed .War.